# R normal distirbution in data frame with threshold

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
    match 1   match 2   match 3   match 4   ....
    0.98      1.23      2.31      0.41
    0.75      0.31      0.99      1.21
    2.10      0.65      1.43      1.17
    1.11      1.87      0.24      1.98
...
```

I have 10,000 columns and ~4000 rows. I would like to find about how many scores in each column are above 2.05. For example, there is 1 in column 1 and 1 in column 3. I would then like to take those numbers and make a histogram/normal distribution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to add some simplifications and benchmarking. Since you have a fair amount of data, speed may be a concern. The `apply()` approaches can be simplified for some speed-up.

Since your data seems to be all numeric, working with a matrix will be *much* faster than a data.frame.

```
df = data.frame(x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100))
mat = as.matrix(df)

f1 = function(df) apply(df,2,function(x)length(which(x>1)))
f2 = function(df) apply(df,2,function(x)sum(x>1))
f3 = function(df) colSums(df > 1)

mbm = microbenchmark::microbenchmark

mbm(f1(df), f2(df), f3(df), f3(mat))
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr    min      lq      mean  median       uq     max neval cld
#   f1(df) 91.460 95.3835 105.86092 98.7045 109.4195 309.392   100   c
#   f2(df) 86.026 92.3655 102.25993 96.8930 107.6085 160.281   100   c
#   f3(df) 60.369 64.1430  71.49276 66.4070  76.9715 114.702   100  b 
#  f3(mat)  7.848  9.0560  11.20236  9.9615  10.5660  51.616   100 a  

identical(f1(df), f2(df), f3(df), f3(mat))
# [1] TRUE
```

So, using `colSums` is a little faster than the `apply()` versions, but converting to a matrix first gives an order of magnitude speed increase.

Comment: so if I use `f3(mat)` will I get a one row matrix with 10,000 columns? And if so: what would be the final code to put that into a histogram/distribution plot? Also, do I need the `identical`?

Comment: The `identical()` just shows that the results are indentical with all the methods---you get the same result with each of the methods. The results are exactly what the other answers name `nc1`. You can call `hist()` on it or `barplot(table())` on it just like the other answers.

Comment: I'm confused. So do I turn my data frame into matrix as `mat=as.matrix(df)` and then use `f3 = function(mat) colSums(mat > 2)` and then a final line of `hist(f3)`?

Comment: Yes---well, you'd have to do `hist(f3(mat))`. The only reason I rolled those up into functions was to make the timing comparison easy. If all you want is the histogram you could do `hist(colSums(as.matrix(df) > 2))`.

Comment: I got an `Error: Invalid number of breaks`, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you could do:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100))

nc1<-apply(df,2,function(x)sum(x>1))

hist(nc1)
```

Comment: I just edited the code, I had an which() that wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: So, the first part I am just generating random numbers to give you an example. The apply(df,2,function(x)sum(x>1)), df is the data frame, 2 means it will apply the function to the columns (if you put 1 instead it will use the rows), and finally the third argument is making a function which is looking for values greater than 1 and counting them

Comment: I'm bad at this stuff, what does the first line do, and what do those 100s specify?

Comment: rnorm() is generating random numbers from a normal distribution. the 100s means that 100 numbers will be generated. Like I said, I did this just as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the previous answer, instead using length to count the number of obs greater than 2.05 in each column and then barplot to display the number by column.

```
      df<- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000)+1,ncol=100,nrow=100))

      nc1<-apply(df,2,function(x) length(which(x>2.05)))

      a = table(nc1)

      barplot(a,ylab="Frequency",xlab="Number of Obs Greater than 2.05")
```

I believe this is the plot that you are looking for.

Comment: I want a histogram of on column scores. Say a lot of columns have 4 scores over 2.05, and then a few have 3 scores over 2.05, and and a few have 5 scores over 2.05. Then I would want a histogram that is centered at 4 and looks somewhat normal. Does that make sense? I don't need the name of column or anything for the histogram

Comment: @Evan  I've edited my previous answer to provide the plot you are looking for.

Comment: thanks! can you explain what the first line of code does?

Comment: `length(which(x > 2.05)` could be simplified to  `sum(x > 2.05)`. For a little more speed and clarity `colSums(df > 2.05)` could replace the entire `apply()`.